# In Lists, is remove same as erase?

Tags: c++, list, c++14

Those are two sample examples of what am I trying to say.

#### First Example.

```
std::list<SomeClass*> somelist;
// we have defined a SomeClass m
```

1. Method `remove`

   ```
   std::remove(somelist.begin(), somelist.end(), m);
   ```
2. Method `erase`

   ```
   auto it = std::find(somelist.begin(), somelist.end(), m);
   if (it != somelist.end()) {
       somelist.erase(it);
   }
   ```

Question: Is there any difference in behavior or performance?

---

#### Second Example.

Well this is the actual purpose of asking that question,

```
std::list<SomeClass*> somelist;
SomeClass* m = nullptr;
```

Using same methods from first example, What would be the behavior, using both methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the standard says:

- Erase:

  ```
  iterator erase(const_iterator position);
  iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
  ```

  > Invalidates only the iterators and references to the erased elements.
- Remove:

  ```
  void remove(const T& value);
  template <class Predicate> void remove_if(Predicate pred);
  ```

  > Erases all the elements in the list referred by a list iterator i for which the following conditions hold: *i == value, pred(*i) != false. Invalidates only the iterators and references to the erased elements.

If you don't have an iterator or a couple of iterators to be used with `erase` and you have to rearrange the element(s) first, using `remove` could be a better choice.

Note that `remove` will drop all the elements matching the predicate and its complexity is:

> Exactly size() applications of the corresponding predicate

On the other side, `find` has still complexity O(N), but it actually stops when it finds the first occurrence that satisfies the condition.
In particular, it's complexity is defined by the standard as:

> At most `last - first` applications of the corresponding predicate.

Where the following is the signature:

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value);
```

Differences in behavior: use your first proposal to drop all the elements matching the predicate, use the second proposal to (find and) drop only the first element matching the predicate.
Differences in performance: same complexity, in the worst case you won't have any benefit (well, in the best case you would have benefits on large containers, for O(N) is irrelevant if N is equal to 100).

To reply to your last question, if you want to remove `nullptr`s from a list and it could happen that there are more than one, prefer `remove` instead of `find`/`erase`.

Comment: They both have `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: @JossieCalderon Yes, I know, it's written in the answer. Keep in mind that often if the complexity is a problem mostly depends on the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking in c++ the remove method / function in C++ is used to remove a specific element within the list that is equal to a variable, and the erase method / function is used to erase a range or a specific element.

Comment: Erase is used to remove itterator. Not the whole list.

Comment: @AhmedAlaa is right in that `Erase` doesn't remove but *can* be used to invalidate the whole list, if start and end iterators are used for the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The two functions differ in what they take as their arguments. One `erase` removes access to the position(s), see below:

```
iterator erase(const_iterator position);
iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

The other `remove` removes access to all that have a certain value, see below:

```
void remove(const T& value);
```

So no, they are not the same. The former is not meant to be used by the client and the latter is.

As for behavior, call `.erase` and `remove` on your `SomeClass` element `m`. **See what happens.**